# How I can check the DataGridView for duplicate values and calculate this to one?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, cells

I have a C# application with two datagridviews and I want that the first datagrid to calculate the positions and put it two the second datagridview.

For example: here is my first datagrid `InputDataGrid`:

```
Position | Description | Value
-------------------------------
001      | test        | 2,5 
002      |             | 1
001      | hello       | 1,5
002      | test2       | 2
```

If I click on a button I want this data in the second datagrid in this form -> `ResultDataGrid`

```
Position | Value
----------------
001      | 4
002      | 3
```

Here is my code: **UPDATE**

private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in InputDataGrid.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value == null)
        {
            break;
        }

           string position = (string)row.Cells[0].Value;
           Double sellvalue = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);

       foreach (DataGridViewRow resultrow in ResultDatagrid.Rows)
       {
           if ((string)resultrow.Cells[0].Value == position)
           {
               Double oldvalue = Convert.ToDouble(resultrow.Cells[1].Value);
               Double newValue = oldvalue + sellvalue;

               resultrow.Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(newValue);
           }
           else 
           {
               resultrow.Cells[0].Value = position;
               resultrow.Cells[1].Value = Convert.ToString(sellvalue);
               ResultDatagrid.Rows.Add(resultrow);
           }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to achieve or what problem you have, please explain.

Comment: I want that my application calculate the same positions and show this in a second datagridview

Comment: The same positions as what? Why have you not been able to do this, what the problem you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit complicated but works:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Contains the text of column0 e.g 001, 002 etc..
        List<string> myListCol0Text = new List<string>();
        //Contains the row index e.g 0, 1 ,2 ,3 etc...
        List<int> myListCol0Index = new List<int>();
        //Contains the strings of the resulting column0 datagrid
        List <string> col0 = new List<string>();
        //Contains the doubles of the resulting column2 datagrid
        List <double> col2 = new List<double>();
        int i = 0, k = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in InputDataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            //Fill two lists with data
            myListCol0Text.Add(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString ());
            myListCol0Index.Add(i);

            i++;
        }

        double dbl = 0D;
        int count = 0;
        bool bl = false ;

        while (myListCol0Text.Count != 0)
        {
            count = myListCol0Text.Count;
            k = 0;
            bl = false;
            dbl = 0D;
            //Compares the first element of myListCol0Text with ALL the next ones.
            //If it finds a dublicate it removes it and in the end removes the first
            //element also
            for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (myListCol0Text[0] == myListCol0Text[k + 1]) //Dublicate
                {
                    if(!bl) //Only the first dublicate is added to col0 list
                    {
                        col0.Add(myListCol0Text[0].ToString());
                        dbl = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[myListCol0Index[0]].Cells[2].Value);
                        dbl += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[myListCol0Index[k + 1]].Cells[2].Value);
                        col2.Add(dbl);
                        bl = true;
                    }
                    else{ //dont add to list but make the addition of the first and third column
                        dbl += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[myListCol0Index[k + 1]].Cells[2].Value);
                        col2[col2.Count -1] = dbl;
                    }

                    //Removes dublicate
                    myListCol0Text.RemoveAt(k + 1);
                    myListCol0Index.RemoveAt(k + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    k++;
                }
            }

            //Removes first element
            myListCol0Text.RemoveAt(0);
            myListCol0Index.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //Add col0 and col2 to the resulting datagrid
        DataGridViewRow row_;

        for (i = 0; i < col0.Count; i++)
        {
            row_ = new DataGridViewRow();

            row_.CreateCells(ResultDatagrid);
            row_.Cells[0].Value = col0[i];
            row_.Cells[1].Value = col2[i].ToString ();

            ResultDatagrid.Rows.Add(row_);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest why would be to perform the sum operation on the underlying data source of the `DataGridView` with just a few lines of code using linq and then use the result as a data source for the other grid:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new List<DataItem>
        {
            new DataItem { Position = "001", Description = "test", Value = 2.5m },
            new DataItem { Position = "002", Description = "", Value = 1m },
            new DataItem { Position = "001", Description = "hello", Value = 1.5m },
            new DataItem { Position = "002", Description = "test2", Value = 2m }
        };

        var results = 
            items
            .GroupBy(x => x.Position, (key, values) => new { Position = key, Values = values })
            .Select(g => new DataItem() 
            { 
                Position = g.Position, 
                Value = g.Values.Sum(x => x.Value) 
            });
    }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```